# Weyl connection

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, mathematics

Considering the Weyl connection $\Gamma^{\lambda}_{\mu\nu}$ in a torsion-free space, defined by the covariant derivative of the metric tensor and a vector field $A_{\lambda}$:

$D_{\lambda}g_{\mu\nu}=A_{\lambda}g_{\mu\nu}$

How can I find the explicit expression for this connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A google search [yields](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1214429379) (page 147)
$$
{\Gamma^i}_{jk}= ^\circ\!\!{\Gamma^i}_{jk} +\frac 12(\delta^i_jA_k +\delta^i_k A_j-g^{im} g_{jk}A_m)
$$
where $^\circ{\Gamma^i}_{jk}$ is the Levi-Civita connection.

Thanks for the question. I did not know this result.

Comment: But how do I use the information that was given to me to obtain that result?

Comment: This is explained in detail in the paper I cited.  It parallels the usual derivation of the Christoffel symbol formula.